# Git showing 'up-to-date' when pulling branch from bash file

Tags: bash, git

I have a bash script that pulls and builds some source code.  If I am on the `master` branch, it works as expected, however if I change to a different branch it says it is already up to date even if there are pushed changes. If I do a `git pull` outside the script from the cmd line, it pulls as expected.

**deploy.sh**

```
echo | git branch
echo "git pull ..."
git pull https://tech-dev:password@bitbucket.org/mycompany/pow-wow.git
```

**Output**

./deploy.sh

```
  master
* spring3upgrade
git pull ...
From https://bitbucket.org/mycompany/pow-wow
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

**Question**

How do I get it to `pull` from the branch I am currently on in the bash script?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `git branch -r` ?

Comment: the `git branch -r` cmd does show the `origin/spring3upgrade` (and `origin/master`).

Comment: well: `git pull` alone will automatically translate to `git pull origin spring3upgrade` ...

Comment: So I should replace `git pull https://tech-dev:password@bitbucket.org/mycompany/pow-wow.git` with just `git pull`?  Is it possible to include the `password` with the `git pull` (the reason why I used the url was to include the credentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*why it doesn't work*

If you are pulling using an explicit URL (as displayed in your question) :

- there is no default refspec, so only the remote `HEAD` (the default branch) is fetched
- there is no default "remote branch" configured for your checked out branch, so `git pull` will merge in whatever that default branch points to (ie: it will try to merge `origin/master`, not `origin/spring3upgrade`)

---

*how to fix it*

The simplest way is to define a named remote (e.g: `origin`), let git set up its default configuration, and have named remote tracking branches:

```
git remote add origin <URL>
git fetch

# for branches that already exist locally:
git switch <branch>
git branch -u origin/branch

# for remote branches not checked out locally:
git switch <branch>  # will automatically take 'origin/<branch>' as a base,
                     # and set it as the upstream branch
```

If you have a special need which requires to not name the remote: you may provide the refspec you need on the command line, probably:

```
# pull the branch which has the same name as your local branch:
git pull <repo> "$(git branch --show-current)"
```

---

You need to provide specific credentials to access your remote. There are many ways to do that :

- a pretty common way is to go through ssh: create an ssh key, configure your central server to accept the public key for a `CI` (you choose the name ...) dedicated user, and set up your builder agent to access your repo through ssh with that key
- or using https, set up a credentials manager (see the link your [posted in your comment](https://www.shellhacks.com/git-config-username-password-store-credentials/), or [`git help credentials`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)), or the many `http.*` settings in [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try add the following to the script: `git switch spring3upgrade` and `git branch -u origin/spring3upgrade`.

Comment: @Richard: for `git branch -u origin/spring3upgrade` to work, you need to have a named remote. It is not clear from your question whether you have one or not, and whether you have an ulterior motive to run `git pull <url>` rather than `git pull origin`.

Comment: I think I do, because `git fetch` shows the `spring3upgrade` branch.

Comment: to list your remotes: `git remote -v`

Comment: `git remote -v`
`origin https://tech-dev@bitbucket.org/mycompany/pow-wow.git (fetch)`
`origin https://tech-dev@bitbucket.org/mycompany/pow-wow.git (push)`

Comment: if I want it to just use the branch that is currently selected locally with credentials, i.e. the branch that git branch shows as selected, can I do that?

Comment: @Richard: yes. it turns out you have a regular setup on your repo, running `git pull` or `git pull origin` will be enough.

Comment: How do I run `git pull` or `git pull origin` with the credentials?

Comment: By storing the credentials, I can then use `git pull`.  https://www.shellhacks.com/git-config-username-password-store-credentials/

Comment: @Richard: exactly. See also [`git help credentials`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)